# Copy files in use available from over a network

Tags: windows-xp

How can I copy files that are in use, and that are available over a network?

I am trying to copy some data files, but it always says that it cannot be copied because the file is in use.

I am using Windows XP, can someone please suggest a way to copy the in-use files over a network?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you would need access to the server the files are stored on, and then do what is known as a *shadow copy*.  [HoboCopy](http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,71415-order,4/description.html) is a good tool for doing shadow copies.

Comment: i did try it but i get this error "There was a COM failure"

Comment: VSS snapshots cannot be created over the network.

Comment: is there any other way to make a copy?

Comment: Not without access to the actual physical server (or it's console through RDP) and an Administrative account.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a combination of hobocopy and psexec. Something like this:

`psexec \remotemachine -u username \path\to\hobocopy \path\to\src \path\to\dest`

Which would run hobocopy on the remote machine, where it would be able to make shadow copies. Note that `\path\to\src` and `\path\to\dest` and `\path\to\hobocopy` are on the *remote* machine, although you could make the destination path something like `\\localmachine\share\path\to\dest` to do a network copy back over to your own machine. Seems like it would be easier just to copy it locally and then go retrieve the file as a separate step.

You'll need to make sure hobocopy is available on the remote machine, too, including installing the C runtime there if necessary.

Comment: Also, the home of hobocopy (I wrote it) is here: http://candera.github.com/hobocopy.